# PowerShell script in setting up multiple SharePoint Alerts

Tags: powershell, alert

Another user (Charlie) is requesting to have alerts sent anytime a change is made on the "discussion board", "Batch Report" folder, "Reports" folder, and "Audits" folder within a single client site. There are 50 client sites with each of these folders.

My question is, instead of manually setting up alerts on 50 sites x 4 folders = 200 alerts, is there so sort of PowerShell script that can be run to potentially automate this task?

Comment: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/11/managing-alerts-using-powershell.html

Comment: @BlueBird, please re-post your response as an answer.  also when you re-post please include the answer in full along with the link.  Links have a tendency to disappear with time and this keeps the answers relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a basic outline of creating an alert using powershell. Combine this with some powershell that iterates through the sites / lists you are hoping to target and you have yourself a good start.

```
$SPsite = Get-SPSite "http://SharePointSite.com"
$SPweb=$SPsite.Rootweb 
$SPlist=$SPweb.lists["Shared documents"] 
$SPuser = $SPweb.EnsureUser('Domain\Salaudeen') 
$SPnewAlert = $SPuser.Alerts.Add() 
$SPnewAlert.Title = "My Custom Alert"
$SPnewAlert.AlertType=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertType]::List 
$SPnewAlert.List = $SPlist
$SPnewAlert.DeliveryChannels = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertDeliveryChannels]::Email 
$SPnewAlert.EventType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventType]::Add 
$SPnewAlert.AlertFrequency = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertFrequency]::Immediate 
$SPnewAlert.Update() 
$SPweb.Dispose() 
$SPSite.Dispose()
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/11/managing-alerts-using-powershell.html#ixzz2OaCHGyYf